# Select all divs but not those in nested in specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this IE7 z-index fixer and it is messing with some specific elements.

What i'm trying to do is selecting all divs, but not the ones nested in a specific div.

Here is the jQuery code I'm currently using, that is not working as intended.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 1000;
        $('div').not('.filter_list_1_container > div').each(function() {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;
        });
    });
</script>
```

For some reason it only ignores the first layer. If the nested divs contains a div the jQuery code does not ignore them either...

How do I ignore all the divs inside the ".filter_list_1_container" class?

Comment: that is because you are specifically ignoring the immediate child divs of .filter_list_1_containe, this may sound silly, but can you remove that '>' symbot and try with just `.filter_list_1_container  div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need descendant insted of direct child so remove `>` from selector.

*Change*

```
.not('.filter_list_1_container > div')
```

*To*
    .not('.filter_list_1_container div')

Your code would be.

```
$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
    $('div').not('.filter_list_1_container div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `>` in your selector, which means that it will only select direct children of that element. If you remove it then it will ignore any descendents of `.filter_list_1_container` that are `div` elements

This will do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 1000;
        $('div').not('.filter_list_1_container div').each(function() {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is that the '>' operator is selecting all direct children. So in the following case..

.filter_list_1_container
|
div 
|
div

It will only exclude the first set of divs and show the second one.

Try removing the '>' operator